# Add custom text to inpt field with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, input

Here I have a google custom search code but Is anybody know how I can add custom text to input field?

CODE:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '004975901999993403229:puwldey9ibm';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Is any way to add text to input field with javascript or jquery...
I was try with:

```
$('#gsc-i-id1').val($('#gsc-i-id1').val() + 'MY CUSTOM TEXT HERE');
```

but dont work!

Comment: you sure this Google custom search script is working?

Comment: yes, try: http://jsbin.com/UgUxEKo/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script>
  $(window).load( function() {
   var input = $('#gsc-i-id1');
   input.val( input.val() + 'MY CUSTOM TEXT HERE');
    alert( input.val())
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, now work but how to automaticly click on search button when page load

Comment: yes, its good, but how to automaticly show results, witout user click on search button

Comment: try $('input.gsc-search-button').click()

Comment: `$(buttonSelector).click()`

Comment: `input.val(function(i,v){ return v + 'My custom text here'; });` don't call the `val()` method twice for no reason.